# how do i add a progress bar using icons on tabulator?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, tabulator

I have a field in my table that shows the execution of a multiple tasks. It should appear as circle icons each with a different colour indicating if the task has been executed on time, early or if there is a delay. And the progress is shown as multiple icons next to each other as shown here:
[progress of execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnKBg.png)

Does anyone have any idea what would be the field type of this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a custom formatter to achieve this.

Full details on custom formatters can be found in the [Formatter Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/format#format-custom)